# Android converting stream to byte array Out of Memory Exceptions

Tags: java, android

I have ran into a situation where I am getting out of memory exceptions when trying to convert an input stream into a byte array. On newer Android phones it's no problem, but some of these cheaper models are experiencing it. Here is the method I'm using. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

```
public byte[] convertStreamToByteArray(InputStream is) throws IOException {
  ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
  int i = 0;
  while ((i = is.read(buff, 0, buff.length)) > 0) {
    baos.write(buff, 0, i);
  }
  return baos.toByteArray();
}
```

Comment: 1) Do you really need to read all those bytes into memory? 2) Can you determine the size of the input stream without reading it all in?

Comment: Notice that `return baos.toByteArray();` will require the data to be held in memory *twice* at the same time, once in the baos and once in the copy of the underlying array where it gets copied to.

Comment: does it appear at the first usage of this code or after a time. consider that this is a stream and closeble. closebale normally needs to be closed, otherwise resource leak can occur.

Comment: @JimmyB I don't think I do need to read them all in. I'm working on raw pcm audio so I need to convert the stream into bytes, then into a short array. Do you have a suggestion to optimize this?

Comment: @HenningLuther I close my input streams right after I call this function, do I need to close the inner input stream reference too?

Comment: @Jeremy im not sure , but i would do since i dont know the implementation. its closable so close it. every ide should give you a warning by not closing closable ressources. but its just a hint and the only thing i can see by now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is, do not copy all the data from the stream to memory.

Why do you need to do so ?

Can't you read and consume the stream data as it comes without holding the whole data in memory ?

If you need some buffering, buffer as small as you can for it to be consumable/processed and throw that buffer away and create a new one so that you have as less memory used at a time as possible.

Answer (score 1):

See if IOUtils can help you out here.

Import it

```
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
```

Then try:

```
public byte[] convertStreamToByteArray(InputStream is) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    IOUtils.copy(is, baos);
    return baos.toByteArray();
}
```

Comment: I just tried this code and am still having the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Try to create an byte array with the size of `InputStream` like this :

```
public byte[] convertStreamToByteArray(InputStream is) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] buff = new byte[is.available()];
    int i = 0;
    while ((i = is.read(buff, 0, buff.length)) > 0) {
        baos.write(buff, 0, i);
    }
    return baos.toByteArray();
```

}